# JComponent not drawing inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Simple problem for Swing regular costumers.

The idea is to load an image and use it as a background of a JPanel through a JComponent object. It seems to load just fine as the image information from `toString()` method is loading properly and the `paintComponent()` method is running, but for some reason it is not rendering correctly inside the JFrame leading to an empty frame. Here's the code:

**RicochetFrame.java**

```
public class RicochetFrame extends JFrame {
  RicochetStartPanel startPanel;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RicochetFrame window = new RicochetFrame();
                window.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
   }

  public RicochetFrame() throws IOException {
    startPanel = new RicochetStartPanel();

    this.getContentPane().add(startPanel);

    this.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

**RicochetStartPanel.java**

```
public class RicochetStartPanel extends JPanel {
  RicochetStartPanel() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("frame_bg.jpg"));
    this.add(new RicochetImagePanel(myImage));

    this.setVisible(true);

    this.validate();
    this.repaint();
  }

}
```

**RicochetImagePanel.Java**

```
public class RicochetImagePanel extends JComponent {
  private Image image;

  public RicochetImagePanel(Image image) {
    this.setVisible(true);

    this.image = image;
  }
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```

Comment: `BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("frame_bg.jpg"));` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RicochetImagePanel` is sizing itself to its preferred size => [0, 0]. Override its `getPreferredSize()` to return the dimensions of the image (if not null). Better still, why not simply display the image as an ImageIcon in a JLabel?